# Does 'remain safe' mean the same as 'stay safe'?

Tags: grammar

Does 'remain safe' mean the same as 'stay safe’?

Context:

> 'Please check on neighbors and friends to make sure they **remain safe** in light of the extreme weather'.

Answer (score 1):

They mean the same thing, but "remain" is more formal.

Comment: Get it now, thx!